# Nginx proxy_cache vs uwsgi_cache

Tags: django, caching, nginx, uwsgi

We want to implement nginx caching for our Django app running via uwsgi.

From resources online it seems that I can use either `proxy_cache` or `uwsgi_cache` configs in nginx. I could not find what is the difference between them as they seem to me identical.

Only difference I can think of is that `proxy_cache` I can use with anything (should we decide to ditch uwsgi) while `uwsgi_cache` is specific to uwsgi.

Would be great if anyone could explain what is the difference between them two.